# Getting data synchronously using map and dataservice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map through some data, and call dataservice with the data. The problem is, i give the dataservice mapped data ID in order, but I received them differently, because the response time for both ID are different. Example:

```
// forms = [3, 133]
  forms.map((formId, index) => {
        // I give the ID's like this - 3, 133
        dataService.getApplianceModelData(formId).then((data) => {
        // I receive the data like this - [133 data], [3 data]
```

I thought the map method is synchronous, but i receive the data asynchronouosly?
The dataservices that is called:

```
  async getApplianceModelData(id) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "/api/1/hardware/appliance_models/" + id + "/",
      {}
    );
    return data;
  }
```

I want to get data like i input it (synchronous), if i map through 3, 133, i want to get first 3 data, and then 133 data. Any advice?

Comment: Does the behaviour change if you replace `forms.map` with `for (const formId of forms)` ?  what are you doing with the data also?

Comment: For loop does not help, i tried for, forEach, map, nothing helps. I'm creating form fields with the data and indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would help you post the full issue and what you have? that should help understand what you are really trying to do.

for what it's worth,

```js
...
forms.map(async (formId, index) => {
  // I give the ID's like this - 3, 133
  const data = await dataService.getApplianceModelData(formId)
  // I receive the data like this - [133 data], [3 data]
...
```

may help preserve your order. Because with what you currently have, it's tempting to think that your `.map` would wait between executions, but that's not going to be the case because when `dataService.getApplianceModelData(formId)` is called, it just proceeds to the next thing (while that promise resolves in the `.then` block

If you do need the values returned from the array `forms.map` you would likely need to have a something that looks like `= await Promise.all(forms.map(async ...`